# Use regex to detach number from dynamic currency

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a function that gets the number from a string(totalPrice). The problem is this string does not have a fixed format but is dynamic. Such as, "$797.48", "CHF 879.00", "1,797.48 €", "€1.234,48", ... And the output need to be "797.48", "879.00", "1797.00", "1234.48" corresponding.

I used regex to detect the number part but seems it does not work well.

```js
const detachNumber = (subtotal) => {
  const rgx = /([1-9]*\,|.?[0-9]*\.|,?[0-9]*)/g
  if(rgx.test(subtotal)) {
    return subtotal.match(rgx).filter(m => !!m).join('')
  }
  return "0.00"
}

const subTotals = ["$797.48", "CHF 1,879.00", "97,48 €", "€ 1.234,48"]
const rs = subTotals.map(detachNumber)
console.log(rs)
```

As you see. The result is `["$797.48", "1,879.00", "97,48", " 1,234.48"]`, which `"$797.48"` is not what I expected. Please help me update the regex then I can achieve it.

And I am still stuck on step formating all these prices become 1 standard, that has only `.` for the decimal. I need a function `format` to do that.
So the process will be:

Input1:

`["$797.48", "CHF 1,879.00", "97,48 €", "€1.234,48"]`

---

Output1,
Input2:

`["797.48", "1,879.00", "97,48", "1.234,48"]`

---

Outout2:

`["797.48", "1879.00", "97.48", "1234.48"]`

So you guys can please help me with this?

Comment: You can try this regex `(?:\d+,)*\d+(?:\.\d+)`

Comment: I think your problem is ambiguous for decimal comma vs. decimal point. How will you distinguish the cases? Is "1,000 EUR" a thousand euros or a single euro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match the format of the occurring numbers. Then for every match, remove the dot or comma if there is a dot or comma present on the right.

If there is a comma left, replace it by a dot.

```js
const regex = /\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?/;
const subTotals = ["$797.48", "CHF 879.00", "1,797.48 €", "€1,234.48", "97,48 €", "CHF 1,879.00"];

const rs = subTotals.reduce((a, s) => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    a.push(m[0]
      .replace(/[.,](?=.*[.,])/g, '')
      .replace(/,/g, '.')
    );
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(rs);
```

Comment: It's not enough to assume that the rightmost period/comma is the decimal point. It is legal to have thousands separators after the decimal point, e.g. "1,234.567,890".

Comment: @Nayuki This solution is based on the examples and expected results of the OP.

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, Thanks for your help. But seem I missed a case `1.749,00 DKK`, that will need to return `1749.00`, but your solution returns `1.749`. Can you help to update the answer?

Comment: @bird You can include the dot in the match `const regex = /\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*/;` See https://ideone.com/TxaXwF

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern: `[\d.,]+`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYPHWa/1)

Code:

```js
const detachNumber = (subtotal) => {
  const rgx = /[\d.,]+/g
  if(rgx.test(subtotal)) {
    return subtotal.match(rgx).filter(m => !!m).join('')
  }
  return "0"
}

const subTotals = ["$797.48", "CHF 1,879.00", "97,48 €", "€1,234.48"]
const rs = subTotals.map(detachNumber)
console.log(rs)
```

Comment: This leaves the comma as a decimal separator for the third value

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that's a bit shorter (and hopefully clearer):

```js
 
const values = ["$797.48", "CHF 1,879.00", "97,48 €", "€1,234.48"]

function format( input ) {
  const [, m1, m2] = input.match(/((?:\d+,?)+)\.(\d{2})|((?:\d+\.?)+),(\d{2})/).filter(Boolean)
 return m1.replace(/[.,]/g, '') + "." + m2
 }
console.log(values.map(v => format(v)))
```